# Javascript date object automatically add one day when creating from date string

Tags: javascript, date

In my javascript i want to convert date from date string.

i have string like

```
date = "Thu Sep 03 2015 19:30:00 GMT+0000"
```

Now i convert string using Date object.

```
var d = new Date(date);
```

But this gives me,

```
Fri Sep 04 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

It automatically add one day into day. What is wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c35eaofp/1/ I get the correct date. Maybe it is because of your timezone. It is adding time to fix it and jump to the next day. In my case, GMT+0200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It automatically add one day into day. What is wrong?

Nothing. The time you input is 19:30 GMT and the timezone on the device you're using is set to GMT+0530. Add 5 hours 30 minutes to 7:30pm and you get 01:00am the following day.

You should not use the Date constructor to parse strings, as it is inconsistent across browsers and until recently, entirely implementation dependent. Manually parse strings, or use a Date library.

Comment: I wish that could work for me.  Maybe it can and I'm simply misunderstanding something: